# Teamviewer linux without permanently running daemon

Tags: linux, teamviewer

Teamviewer Linux has the annoying property of installing a permanently running daemon. This not only consumes resources but also presents a security risk. You can disable the daemon startup, however then the teamviewer client does not work anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to enable the daemon before running the teamviewer script and disable it again after the teamviewer client has closed.

The following shell script handles things automatically:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo starting teamviewer daemon
sudo teamviewer --daemon enable
teamviewer &
wait $!
echo teamviewer finished
sudo teamviewer --daemon disable
echo stopped and disabled teamviewer daemon
```

Comment: I get this error:
```$ sudo teamviewer --daemon disable
[sudo] password for usuario: 

Init...
 *** TeamViewer can not be executed with sudo! ***
 Either use your normal user account without sudo
 or use a the real root account to log in to your desktop (not recommended!).
```

Comment: what teamviewer version are you using? Just checked with the latest deb for ubuntu/debian (12.0.76279) and i don't get you error message

Comment: with my version, `teamviewer --daemon enable` should be just `teamviewer daemon enable`

Comment: Not only does it listen on a port, when you might only want to use it as a client (see question) it also now won't run as a non root account as it's a systemd service nowadays. Awesome!

Comment: What a crap to have this daemon running all the time! That's a reason for me to not use TeamViewer any longer.

Comment: Came here for this, tried it, and nope, teamviewerd still shows up in ps.

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu 18.04, here how I solve this

Stop autostart demon

```
$sudo systemctl disabled teamviewerd.service
```

create script /opt/tm.sh

`#!/bin/bash
pkexec --user root systemctl start teamviewerd.service;
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer;
pkexec --user root systemctl stop teamviewerd.service;`

Set bash script executable

`chmod u+x /top/tm.sh`

Update de /usr/share/applications/com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.desktop

`Exec=/opt/tm.sh`

It work perfecly for my needs. I only need to connect to other computer never to mine, so root deamon always running is not needed.

Let's see how it live with update from ppa of Teamviewer

Answer (score 1):

The solution Fedora 30+ is:

```
# systemctl disable teamviewerd.service
# systemctl stop teamviewerd.service
```

But don't forget to start the service again in order to get a TeamViewer ID.

```
# systemctl start teamviewerd.service
```

Comment: it's enabled again after teamviewer update

Comment: yes, it seems to be that the installation package is not taking care the current status which badly is often the case. Like the Docker package of the official Docker repository is overriding your current systemd unit without asking.

Answer (score 1):

The [tar package](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/30664-use-the-tar-package-for-linux) allows to run the TV client without installation and without root privileges.